# Where does vscode store the "find in files" history?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The find in files (Search) pane keeps a history of both the search expression and the "files to include" and "files to exclude" expressions. Where are theses stored? I want to remove some of the "files to exclude" expressions which contain typos (e.g. `*.taml` instead of `*.yaml`).